Movie where kids are transported to an unknown planet in the galaxy/universe
I only saw the trailer for this several years ago (post 2000's) about earth being able to transport people to a planet that they don't know where it is. The trailer described it as a, now contest, that whoever discovered first where they were in the universe would get some kind of reward.  It also seemed like they couldn't necessarily get back easily or at all.  I'm fairly certain I saw it on Apple Movie trailers and most likely before 2010 if that helps.  
I also believe the kids were part of an academy or school, and it was voluntary.  Also there seemed to have sent other people before but with obviously no success.

You're looking for Sol, but it's from 2012. From IMDb:

The story revolves around teams of young people who are playing an galactic game called Sol. Teams of youths are transported to planets throughout the galaxy without knowing which planet they will land on and the winner is the first person to find our sun (Sol) in the night sky. Something goes wrong from the start and therein lies the story.

A group of teens is stranded there, and they have to work together to survive. Here's the trailer:



